# Inverse of ST_RasterToWorldCoord() in PostGIS?

Tags: postgis

*Is there an inverse function of [ST_RasterToWorldCoord()](https://postgis.net/docs/RT_ST_RasterToWorldCoord.html) in PostGIS (or the underlying GEOS/gdal), which, given the coordinates of a point in the raster's SRS, returns its row and column number?*

I searched terms `st_worldcoordtoraster` and found nothing. I imagine it is not too difficult to write such a conversion function, but just wanted to ask here to avoid reinventing the wheel.

(I'm using the latest PostGIS 3.3 beta)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That would be [`ST_WorldToRasterCoord`](https://postgis.net/docs/RT_ST_WorldToRasterCoord.html):

```
record ST_WorldToRasterCoord(raster rast, geometry pt);

record ST_WorldToRasterCoord(raster rast, double precision longitude, double precision latitude);
```

> Returns the upper left corner as column and row given geometric X and Y (longitude and latitude) or a point geometry. [...]

---

References:

- PostGIS [*Raster Accessors*](https://postgis.net/docs/RT_reference.html#Raster_Accessors)

  in the
- PostGIS [*Raster Reference*](https://postgis.net/docs/RT_reference.html)